# STR class error when deploying lumen to hosting

Tags: laravel, cpanel, lumen

I was Deplyoying my lumen project to cpanel hosting , i did it as usual same as other person but i keep getting this error

'''
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/k5169896/public_html/apiFunderAsia/vendor/illuminate/support/Str.php on line 681
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually caused by the version of PHP you are using, check the version on your new host, if it is < PHP 7.2 which is the minimum requirement for Lumen then it causes this issue.